# How do I restrict a window component to drag just inside a contentpanel on GXT - GWT?

Tags: gwt, gxt

How do I restrict a window component to drag just inside a contentpanel on GXT - GWT?

I need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When setting your draggable utlize the setContainer portion and that tells the draggable object that it is constrained too that container only and hence will not be dragged out of it.

Check the Draggable help online regarding this.